Getting dapp could be malicious warning during phantom wallet transaction
Hi I have deployed my spl-token program to mainnet-beta recently, so its publicly available but from last two days I am getting warning "This dapp could be malicios" warning on phantom wallet during transaction, Can someone let me know why this warning is coming to my dapp?

Email blowfish to unflag your site review@blowfish.xyz
Use signAndSendTransaction Method https://docs.phantom.app/solana/sending-a-transaction

Hi, blow fish team is asking for "having someone known and established in the Solana developer community reach out to them" on behalf of us, Can someone suggest whom to reach and where to get my dapp whitelisted?

same problem here

@subhajitdas did you get this sorted ?

I don't have friends that are "known and established" in the Solana developer community. I asked how else I could verify that I wasn't malicious and got ghosted.
Not sure what other options are there...

true I am also trying to get help from someone but no one is responding. I am wondering why they put such kind of flagging, everytime we have to be dependent on Solana core devs, who are not responding

We have developed a Web3 project that currently supports user logins via several wallets, including the Phantom Wallet. However, we have encountered an issue where users attempting to log into our platform using Phantom Wallet are receiving a notification that our site, https://tagger.pro/, is not on your whitelist; this warning suggests that the site is unknown and may pose security risks.
We kindly request that our domain be added to your whitelist to prevent these warnings and ensure a smooth user experience. Alternatively, we would appreciate any technical assistance you could provide to help us resolve this issue.
We look forward to your response.
Best,
Tagger Team

Hey i saw you platform. how do you solved the problem? Actually I am facing the same problem for my platform
